# Linux mail command line : file input turns into attachment

Tags: linux, bash, email

I want to send the content of the file in a mail, NOT as attachment, i use :

```
mail -s "subject" email_address < filepath
```

but when i receive the mail, it's an attachment, with no file extension nor origin name. I think that the file content is somehow interpreted (it's a diff).
I don't want an attachment, i want the content of file A to be the body of my mail.

Thanks

Comment: maybe some non-ascii character in the body, at the beginning email was designed for ascii characters in the body, after some extensions were done, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME see also `man mail` `/Character sets`

Answer (score 0):

What about 'cat filepath | mail -s "subject" email_address' ?